# Use symbol instead of bounding box in object detection/tracking algorithm

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, object-detection, bounding-box

I need to detect and track different objects on road. I am using YoloR and DeepSort for it. I want the output to be symbols for each objects detected. For example if a car is detected, I want to display the output a car symbol instead of the traditional bounding box.
Is it possible to get such a kind of output ?

**This is the deepsort code from the AIGuy repo**

```
    # draw bbox on screen
            color = colors[int(track.track_id) % len(colors)]
            color = [i * 255 for i in color]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 2)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-30)), (int(bbox[0])+(len(class_name)+len(str(track.track_id)))*17, int(bbox[1])), color, -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, class_name + "-" + str(track.track_id),(int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-10)),0, 0.75, (255,255,255),2)
 # if enable info flag then print details about each track
            if FLAGS.info:
                print("Tracker ID: {}, Class: {},  BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): {}".format(str(track.track_id), class_name, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3]))))
```

Comment: what do you mean by car symbol instead of the bounding box? you want to print like an emoji of a car instead of text?

Comment: Ya i want the output to be like a symbol/emoji/icon instead of the traditional bounding box and and the text/id